# Docusign Authorization for multiple users application

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

For an application where multiple users are sending documents for signature, is the recommended approach to get those users to login to DocuSign using Oauth or can we use the Send On Behalf Of functionality to send from a single admin account?

What permissions are required to use the Send On Behalf Of functionality? I tried sending from an admin account on sandbox and retrieved an authorization error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what type of DocuSign integration you are building. With DocuSign only senders need an account (signers don't need one).

If you are building a integration where each end user will authenticate with the DocuSign platform and use their account to send then yes you want to use OAuth. This integration type is referred to as a [User Application](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#common-user).

Otherwise, if you are building a [Service Integration](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#common-service) where you have a single account associated with the integration "under the hood" then you could allow your app's users to send through that account.

<del>In terms of SOBO (Send on Behalf Of), you can only send on behalf of users that are in the same account.</del>

### Updated Feb 2, 2021

OAuth JWT grant is used when there is no DocuSign account holder available to authenticate themself to the application. JWT grant enables the application itself to impersonate a user. The user must [grant consent](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent) to the application to be impersonated.

Comment: Thanks Ergin.Have you tried SOBO feature using the URL "https://account-d.docusign.net/oauth/userinfo".I am getting authorization error.Is this valid URL?

Comment: Thanks please accept the answer if it answered your original question.  Regarding your SOBO + OAuth question- unfortunately SOBO does not work with OAuth, you need to use legacy or one of the other forms of authentication.